# Custom image size not displaying with wp_get_attachment_image()

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, attachments

I created a custom image size for my portfolio thumbnails

```
add_image_size( 'gallery-thumb', 240, 180, true );
```

I created a shortcode to display all images using a lightbox with lazy loading to generate the following HTML:

```
<a href="/wp-content/uploads/mobile-responsive-website.png" data-lightbox="gallery" title="">
  <img width="240" height="180" src="" class="image_zoom" alt="" loading="lazy" data-src="/wp-content/uploads/mobile-responsive-website-240x180.png">
</a>
```

1. The href needs to be the full size image
2. The image custom size image (gallery-thumb) needs to load into data-src for lazy loading (with no src)

For the image, I used `wp_get_attachment_image()`

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image(   $attachment_id, 
                                                'gallery-thumb', 
                                                false, 
                                                array(  'class' => 'lazy image_zoom', 'data-src' => $url, 'src' => '') );
```

BUT, this doesn't work, the image is loading the full size, not the custom size (see below).  I have checked the URL and the custom size exists... Is there a problem with `wp_get_attachment_image()` and custom sizes?

```
<img width="240" height="180" src="" class="lazy image_zoom" alt="" loading="lazy" data-src="/wp-content/uploads/mobile-responsive-website.png">
```

The size it is loading is the full size with the correct width and height settings (so it is scaling the image) - How do I force it to load the cropped custom image size?

Full Shortcode:

```
function add_gallery($attr) {
    
    $output = '';
    
    if ( !empty( $attr["ids"] ) )
    {
        $ids = explode(",", $attr["ids"]);
    }
    
    if( isset($ids) ) { 
    
        $output .= '<div class="row gallery">';
          
        foreach( $ids as $attachment_id ) 
        {
            $url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, 'full', false);
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image(   $attachment_id, 
                                                'gallery-thumb', 
                                                false, 
                                                array(  'class' => 'lazy image_zoom', 'data-src' => $url, 'src' => '') );       
            
            $alt = get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
            
            if ( !empty($image) )
            {
                $output .= '<div class="col grid_4_of_12">';
                $output .= '  <a href="'.$url.'" ';
                $output .= '     data-lightbox="gallery" title="'.$alt.'">';
                $output .=      $image;
                $output .= '  </a>';
                $output .= '</div>';
            }
        }
        
        $output .= '</div>';
    }
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('my_gallery','add_gallery');
```

Comment: That can happen when the custom image size doesn't exist (not registered or may have been removed somewhere afterwards), so where do you call that `add_image_size()`?

Comment: The image is definitely there. It's not a "does not exist" problem. It is registered - I am using it on other pages in different manner. I believe that this may be a bug. add_image_size() is in functions.php

Comment: What's the output of `echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, 'gallery-thumb' );` ? How about `var_dump( get_intermediate_image_sizes() );` - does it include `gallery-thumb` ? If yes, then I guess a plugin is modifying the output of `wp_get_attachment_image()` or part of it.

Comment: Thanks for your persistence @SallyCJ. I found the issue. It's in the code right there in front of my face. With your tests I found the bad code.  I'm setting `src=''` ... then setting `data-src` to `$url` (which is the full size image URL...) Of course it wont use the custom size if I'm forcing it to use the full size!

Comment: Well.. I did notice the `$url` being set to the full-sized image URL, but I wasn't - since the very beginning - aware the variable was used in that `data-src` attribute! :p Anyway, glad you got it sorted. :)